# Where to get the total volume of MBS (Mortgage Backed Security) purchase by FRB

Tags: mbs

It looks one of the QE by FRB is via MBS according to [The Real Lender on Your Mortgage Could Be the Federal Reserve](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-07-01/the-real-lender-on-your-mortgage-could-be-the-federal-reserve).

The sign of tightening QE can be measured by looking at the total volume of MBS purchased by FRB.

Where and how the amount of MBS that FRB has purchased or sold can be acquired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the table at https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/soma-holdings to get a picture of current holdings. If you want to get a sense for how the holdings have changed over time look at the **SOMA Historical Data Export Builder** section at the bottom of the web page. In particular, you can obtain this information by using the NY Fed's Market Data API.